# How to set default wallpaper for virtual user?

Tags: user-management, user-profile

I am logging in user as virtual user to Sitecore. For some reason default wallpaper for user is blue screen instead of default Sitecore field image. 
[image]
if I update wallpaper manually via dialog it save value somewhere and show correct wallpaper even for next login. 
[image]

I tried this code. It works for common Sitecore user but does not work virtual user.

```
 virtualUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty("Wallpaper", "/sitecore/shell/themes/backgrounds/Field.jpg");
```

How can I setup wallpaper for virtual user? (Sitecore 8.2)

Comment: can you try to `virtualUser.Profile.Save()` after `virtualUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(...)`?

Comment: @TamásTárnok yes. it did not help.

Comment: Does it happen right away?  virtual user client data gets flushed, every 4 hours by default. <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CompactClientDataAgent" method="Run" interval="04:00:00"/>

Comment: @MarkCassidy yes. it does not show me default field image immediately after login.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem could be is that you are using the following:

```
virtualUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty("Wallpaper", "/sitecore/shell/themes/backgrounds/Field.jpg")
```

Try to use the following:

```
virtualUser.Profile["Wallpaper"] = "/sitecore/shell/themes/backgrounds/Field.jpg"
```

**Explanation**

The `SetCustomProperty` does not check if the user is virtual user or not, but the `[]` checks it and it saves into the `user.RuntimeSettings.Properties` if the user is virtual.